# Using Chrome Devtools, I have the resolution @ 1680px, but a min-width:1440px media query is not working

Tags: html, css

So my customer screen is @ 1680px, but screen is 1200px, so I have to use Chrome's Devtools to emulate a larger screen. I created a media query in my css file:

```
@media (min-width: 1440px)
```

But Chrome is using the smaller query when I have the resolution set to 1680px in Devtools:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px)
```

I don't know if its Devtools, or Chrome, or something I did. The page im working on is http://www.becoming1percent.com/ and only section I have so far with that larger media query is the section that says "The Entrepreneurs Monthly Book Box", and the div its in (the class is .hero-content). Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how did you order your query. I saw your code is

```
@media (min-width: 1440px) {
    #index-hero .hero-content {
        margin: -300px auto 15px;
    }
}


@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    #index-hero .hero-content {
        margin: -60px auto 15px;
        /*text-align: left;*/
        width: 50%;
    }

    #index-hero {
    min-height: 900px;
    margin-top: -50px;
    }
}
```

So basically browser will apply `@media (min-width: 1440px)` first then override it with style defined in `@media (min-width: 1200px)`.

`min-width` is often used for mobile first approach so everything will go from smaller to larger screen, for example mobile -> tablet (`min-width: 480px`) -> normal desktop (`min-width: 768px`) -> large screen (`min-width: 1024px`)

So I suggest you re-order the stylesheet, bring 1440px down below 1200px.

Or you can define the max-width to control deeply.

```
 @media (min-width: 1440px) {
    #index-hero .hero-content {
        margin: -300px auto 15px;
    }
}


@media (min-width: 1200px) and (max-width: 1439px) {
    #index-hero .hero-content {
        margin: -60px auto 15px;
        /*text-align: left;*/
        width: 50%;
    }

    #index-hero {
    min-height: 900px;
    margin-top: -50px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't know CSS did that - good to know. I will try this and come back.

Comment: Yeah, the order from top to bottom of CSS is very important :)

Comment: Well, I'll be a son of diddley - that worked, and I learn something new everyday. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Get firefox portable at :

http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable

Then use CTRL+Shift+M to get the mobile emulator.

Much better than the chrome one.

The chrome one gets affected by addons and is buggy, the firefox one with a fresh install works 100% and is very fast for real time resizing also, great to show clients

Comment: I have Firefox installed and it was giving me the same results. But i (well, @trungk18) figured it out. It was because of the order of my @media queries.